# Thunderbird 102: show one recipient per line when composing new email

Tags: email, thunderbird, css, xul

in new Thunderbird 102, a redesign was made:

When composing new email, multiple recipients are shown on one line, instead of one-recipient-per line as it used to be.

[image]

For comparison, here is how it looked originally on Thunderbird 68:

[image]

**Is there any way I can revert back to the old design?
I am happy to modify `omni.ja` if that solves the problem**

Comment: It would be good to know for what reason you need the old design back, so maybe there's a workaround. Helpful hint: in TB 102 you can drag-and-drop addresses between the TO, CC and BCC fields.

Comment: @1NN - I need the old design back, because this new redesign is obfuscated and unclear. The old design was perfect, no reason to change it.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: No. But you might want to try [SeaMonkey](https://www.seamonkey-project.org/).

**Long answer**:

This is a change which was introduced in TB 78 (more than 3 years ago), and it is explained in [Thunderbird's "addressing an email" support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/addressing-email).

As is clear from that article, there's no supported possibility to change this as it is seen as a more efficient way of handling things.

The [list of available extensions](https://addons.thunderbird.net/En-us/thunderbird/extensions/composition/?sort=updated) currently does not feature anything remotely related to your request. Also, the addressing bar is not among  [the UI elements which can be modified by extensions](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/mailextensions/supported-ui-elements).

You could try to check the [list of email clients](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Email_clients_based_on_Thunderbird) based on thunderbird, to see if you find something which works for you.

Or, a sure bet seems to be [Seamonkey](https://www.seamonkey-project.org/), which according to the [screenshots of the UI](https://www.seamonkey-project.org/doc/screenshots) supports exactly what you are looking for, and is built on the same [Gecko Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)) which was initially used for Thunderbird. (I have never used SeaMonkey myself, though). Seamonkey supports [migrating your profile from thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_migration_-_SeaMonkey).